# Firing Ajax call when click submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my Rails 3.1 application I have a Jquery dialog that pops up when clicked, and inside that you have a submit button. I have made somewhat an attempt at making this 'submit' button ajax. So that when it is clicked it updates the appointment time and date. I have the following code:

```
<% if @booking.id and current_user.is_booking_manager? %>
<button id="confirm_appointment">
    test confirmation
</button>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="confirm_appointment_dialog" title="Test Confirm Booking">
        <%= form_for @booking, :url => booking_confirmation_path(@booking), :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :confirmed_appointment %>
        <br />
        <b>Clear provisional appointment:</b><%= check_box_tag "make_unexpected" %>
        <br />
        <%= f.submit :class => 'submit_me' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Application.js**

```
$('.submit_me').bind('change', 
function() {
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

Is there something I am missing

Comment: does it update after your reloaded the page? in that case you need to define a create.js.erb or an update.js.erb and update the page there.
also, the bind code is not neccessary as far as i know, because the :remote => true in your form instantiation makes the form "ajax" already

Comment: Yes it does update after the page is reloaded

Comment: So you saying that I should create a update.js.erb and place my javascript inside that?

Comment: you need to tell your browser to reload the parts of the page, that have new information. your controller automatically looks for a view with the name of the action that was called in the controller, this is where you need to put the javascript to update your page.

Comment: So I need my controller to look at the js to look at the controller and respond to that?

Comment: can you post the rest of your view code? i'll try and respond with an example, which might help understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't update your View, after the JS request is processed. First you need to add an id to the HTML-Element you want to update.

Your Pastie had this Code:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= f.label :confirmed_appointment %></td>
  <td> <% f.hidden_field :confirmed_appointment %>
  <% if @booking.confirmed_appointment %>
  <%= l @booking.confirmed_appointment %>
  <% else %> <em>unconfirmed</em> <% end %> </td>
</tr>
```

In order to make it easy to reference the part you want to update in JavaScript, let's add an id to that td.

```
  <td id="booking-confirmation"> <% f.hidden_field :confirmed_appointment %>
```

After that you need to create an update.js.erb in your views/ folder. Now you can put the line

```
  $("#booking-confirmation").html("<%= l @booking.confirmed_appointment %>");
```

In there, which will look for a field with the id "booking-confirmation" in your HTML and update it.

Lastly, be sure to include

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
 end
```

In your action, to make the action respond to JS calls.

Answer (score 0):

Change `bind('change') -> bind('click')`

Ok, you doing this slightly wrong, http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/19/unobtrusive-ajax-with-rails-31/ try to use this guide

Comment: I did this and still encountering the same thing.

Comment: However when I manually click the refresh button it will say that it has been updated, which is not what I should have to be doing